# Unusual RJS error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am getting the following error in my RoR application:
RJS error:

TypeError: element is null

Element.update("notice", "Comment Posted");
Element.update("allcomments", "\n\n\n  \n\n    waht now?\n\n  \n\n    \n\n  \n\n    asdfasdfa\n  \n\n  \n\n    asdfasdf\n  \n\n\n\n
\n");

But when I hit the refresh button, I can see my partial updated.

Here's my code:

show_comments View:

```
<table>
<% comments.each do |my_comment| %>
  <tr>

    <td><%=h my_comment.comment%></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>
```

show View:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="rescale">
      <div class="img-main">
        <%= image_tag @deal.photo.url %>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="description">
    <p class ="description_content">
      <%=h @deal.description %>
    </p>
    </div>
    </div>
    <p>
      <b>Category:</b>
      <%=h @deal.category %>
    </p>

    <p>
      <b>Base price:</b>
      <%=h @deal.base_price %>
    </p>

    <%#*<p>%>
      <%#*<b>Discount:</b>%>
      <%#=h @deal.discount %>
    <%#*</p>%>

    <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_deal_path(@deal) %> |
    <%= link_to 'Back', deals_path %>

    <p>
      <%= render :partial=>'deal_comments', :locals=>{
          :comments=>Comment.new(:deal_id=>@deal.id)} %>
    </p>
    <div id="allcomments">
      <%=  render :partial=>'show_comments', :locals=>{
        :comments=>Comment.find(@deal.comments)} %>
    </div>
```

Controller:

```
    def create
        @comment = Comment.new(params[:comment])
        render :update do |page|
          if @comment.save
            page.replace_html 'notice', 'Comment Posted'
          else
            page.replace_html 'notice', 'Something went wrong'
          end
          page.replace_html 'allcomments', :partial=> 'deals/show_comments',
            :locals=>{:comments=> @comment.deal.comments}
        end
  end

  def show_comments
    @deal = Deal.find(params[:deal_id])
    render :partial=> "deals/show_comments", :locals=>{:comments=>@deal.comments}
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see a DOM element with the ID of 'notice' - am I missing something? You do have an element with that ID I presume, otherwise, yes you would get a null exception.

Comment: oh right, thanks a lot stef!
i had commented out that part from my layout view and forgot to un-comment it.

Comment: @rrn, you should note this question as solved by checking the previous answer. It would be a good retribution to it's author...